# Is it possible to open an on-disk .md file in chrome, make edits and save back to disk?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, markdown

I am helping to write a feature rich training manual for a technology that changes very regularly.  To do this, I wrote a markdown document which is then converted to HTML using pandoc.  CSS and javascript is added to give it buttons and make it look nice.

At first I created a button which would tracks what section the user is looking at on screen and should have allowed them to open the .md file from disk and edit the content with the user's favorite IDE... As I found out though, for security reasons, no modern browser supports this functionality.  However would it be possible for the user to open up the target .md file in chrome or other modern browser, make edits and then save those files to their disk?

I found a feature for chrome which allows for text editing, but I don't know if it has the guts necessary to make this functionality practical.

```
data:text/html, <body contenteditable>
```

If anyone has an idea of how to implement this feature using chrome or some other method, I would be very grateful.

Comment: For obvious security reasons, a website (even a local html file) doesn't have access to the local hard disk (or well, anything outside of the browser). You could however write a browser plugin. Plugins still have a lot of restrictions, but they can access the local FileSystem.

Comment: If a browser plugin really isn't an option, the only 2 other solutions that come to mind would be a local webserver that serves the file. Then use a server side script to save changes to the document. Or have Javascript create a new `.md` file and offer it to the user as a download after editing is finished.

Comment: @icecub, Is it that obvious though?  I am a pretty ignorant when it comes to web development, but I imagine that  *browsers must be able to at least read from their disk?  Is that not how media is displayed for on-disk html pages?  I am not trying to be facetious, I am just dont know how the internet works.

Comment: Of course servers have access to the local FileSystem. They have software installed which allows this. But a browser is not a server. The browser does have very limited access to the FileSystem. Otherwise it wouldn't be able to read images embedded in local HTML files for example. But it cannot actually write towards the FileSystem. Imagine you visiting my website and my website would be able to access your hard disk. That would be very alarming.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining this in the wrong way. It's not the browser itself that has limited access. It's the websites loaded in the browser that do. Maybe that makes more sense. Since most of time you do not control the code behind a website, your browser protects you by preventing websites from doing stuff that can harm your computer.

Comment: I’m a little confused about your set up here... you’re trying to serve an html file from some server, allow the user to download an open a markdown file in their IDE of choice, then have them save to disk? For what purpose?

Comment: @bryan60 In simple words: He wrote a markdown document and wants to open / edit / save this inside a browser using html / javascript. Which is not possible because websites don't have access to the local filesystem.

Comment: but where is this markdown file to begin with? Is it being served? Is it on the users system? Is the browser just being leveraged as a viewer? There’s a chance this can all be done depending on the set up. The specific use case matters

Comment: @bryan60 The MD is local on the disk.  The browser serves as a cross-platform viewer since this document has to be opened on both Linux and Windows systems with various installed software.  The one thing every machine has is a browser.  The files will be zipped and then sent to users/machines that need it.  At no point in time is this document allowed to be on the internet, but it might be possible to serve it over the corporate network.

Comment: so why can't users just open the markdown file in a text editor and edit it if they need to?

Comment: @bryan60  The document is gigantic and the would-be maintainers are expensive but less tech savy guys.  I was hoping to make a process improvement by providing a user interface so that if they see an error or outdated information while reading all they need to do is click a button and it opens up the .md file they need to edit (There are like 50 or so .md files to make this book which are concatenated with a batch script before pandoc converts them to HTML).

Comment: They’re savvy enough to write markdown and run a batch script but not to run a find in files to get the section they need? Idk, unfortunately in this set up there actually isn’t much you can do. Maybe just write an editing utility that will do what your button is trying to do?